# Convert datatable into XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I convert XML into datatable and now want to convert data table into XML again.
I have database in which four XML's are there and have to change that text xml

```
public ActionResult getChangeContent(string arg, string content)
{
    char[] a = { ':' };
    string[] id = arg.Split(a);
    decimal tid = Convert.ToDecimal(id[0]);
    decimal jid = Convert.ToDecimal(id[1]);
    string groupname = id[2];
    var gp = (from Trans_Mast in r2ge.Transcription_Master where Trans_Mast.Transcription_Id == tid && Trans_Mast.Entity_Id == jid select Trans_Mast).Distinct();

    foreach (var g in gp)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(g.Text_xml)));
        DataTable text = ds.Tables[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (text.Rows[i]["group"].Equals(groupname))
            {
                text.Rows[i]["Text_Text"] = content;
            }
            text.AcceptChanges();
        }
        ConvertDatatableToXML(text);
    }
    return View();
}

public string ConvertDatatableToXML(DataTable dtTemp)
{
    MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
    dtTemp.WriteXml(str, true);
    str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str);
    string xmlstr;
    xmlstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return (xmlstr);
}
```

Data set is changed but there is no affect on XML.. any suggestion please..

Comment: are you able to see the changes in the text while passing it to the function (ConvertDataTableToXML()). debug your code what value is going and is it same value there in xml..

Comment: value is changed but not in XML ..it makes change in dataset only

Answer (score 0):

use this piece of code :

```
private static string ConvertDataTableToXML(DataTable dtBuildSQL)    
{    
    DataSet dsBuildSQL = new DataSet();    
    StringBuilder sbSQL;    
    StringWriter swSQL;    
    string XMLformat;    

    sbSQL = new StringBuilder();    
    swSQL = new StringWriter(sbSQL);

    dsBuildSQL.Merge(dtBuildSQL, true, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);    
    dsBuildSQL.Tables[0].TableName = “Table”;

    foreach (DataColumn col in dsBuildSQL.Tables[0].Columns)    
    {
        col.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
    }

    dsBuildSQL.WriteXml(swSQL, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    XMLformat = sbSQL.ToString();
    return XMLformat;    
}
```

Comment: when I write                 ds.WriteXml("C:/project/Text_xml.xml"); then in particular foldar xml is created with change but in database still no affect on xml